# get entries by date component in core data

Tags: ios, swift, date, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I want to filter entries from my database by single date components such as month=12. Notice that I can't query for entries with dates between to fixed dates because the year might be different.

It should look/work like this:

```
let request = NSPredicate(format: "date.month=%i", 12)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a time interval for the predicate.

```
NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@ && date < %@", aDate, aDate.date(byAddingMonths:1))
```

Please note that you perhaps mixed up the `NSFetchRequest` with the `NSPredicate` in your question.

To add a month:

```
extension Date {
   func date(byAddingMonths months: Int) -> Date {
       var diff = DateComponents()
       diff.month = months
       return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: diff, to: self)!
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

After clarifying the question, it appears you need a month attribute. Add an  `Int` attribute to your entity that should be filled out with the month automatically whenever you change the date (override `didSet`). Here is how you get the month from the date:

```
let month = Calendar.current.component(.month, from:theDate)
```

Comment: Edited my question. As far as I understand your approach would refer to a specific date range of a single month in a a year. Correct? I need to find every entry with lets say month=11 irregardless of the year.

Comment: @matteok There's no really good way to do that, since `Date` does not include month information. You'd have to use this answer repeatedly for dates in different years.